# Laravel Dispatch Job - check if dispatched?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Amazon SQS driver for Laravel Queue Job.

I want to inform the user that the job has been dispatched in the Queue. How do I check this before returning response to the user?

For example:

```
dispatch(new UploadJob($request->all()));

return $this->respond(['status' => 'In Queued']); // Is it really in queue?
```

Comment: There'd be an exception with the `dispatch` call if SQS wasn't accessible, wouldn't there?

Comment: @ceejayoz If that the case, what exception i should catch if not in queue?

Comment: I'd catch `\Exception`. Presumably, *any* exception in the `dispatch` call means it didn't make it to SQS. `try { dispatch(...) } catch(\Exception $e) { // didn't work }`

Comment: You can put an Event in your Job, and listen it.

Answer (score 0):

The job does not get dispatched until the pending job is destroyed. It is not always clear when that happens, especially in something like a pipeline, where one step in the pipeline may rely on a job being successfully dispatched in a previous pipeline step. Meanwhile the pipeline steps don't get destroyed until the end, so the actual dispatch does not happen until after all the dependencies of a successful dispatch have been completed.

So, it is possible to force the dispatch early, simply by destroying the pending job object.

```
$pendingJob = dispatch(new UploadJob($request->all()));
unset($pendingJob); // Dispatch happens here.
```

Wrap that up in a `try...catch` if you want to act on it.